# How to make rails API able to accept json params instead of http

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Generic rails API use jbuilder for rendering result.

The http params used to send data to rails API server, like this:

```
POST user_id=10&post[0][msg]=text&post[1][post_id]=15&post[1][msg]=message
```

How to make API able to accept json inbound params instead of http, like this:

```
POST {user_id:10,post:[{msg:'text'},{post_id:15,msg:'message'}]}
```

Comment: That should already work when you pass a json content-type in your Post request.

Comment: This actually is the answer.

Comment: @Julia make copy as the answer.

Comment: Also you can limit your responses with `respond_to :json` in your controller. This would automatically trigger a `406 Not Acceptable` if a request for a format is made which is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment by @Julia Will this question is closed.

The answer is: pass `content-type` HEADER. (or in rails use `.json` at the end of the url)